# For-loop printing oddly

Tags: python, for-loop

Here's the basic code I'm working with:

```
hobbies = []

for i in range(3):
    hobby = raw_input("What are your three favorite hobbies?")
    hobbies.append(hobby)

print hobbies
```

My answers were "ok", "k", "ok". The hobbies list will print:

```
[u'ok', u'k', u'ok']
```

What's with the "u"?

Comment: `u` stands for [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Instead try `print(', '.join(hobbies))`

Comment: That should not be something that you should worry about. Like the first comment said, It only states that the text is in unicode. This will not affect the printing each individual hobby. If for aesthetic reasons you want to print it out without the `u`  you could `map(lambda x: x.encode('ascii'), hobbies` before printing `hobbies`